# Remove shutdown/reset dialog keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, osx-yosemite

I am often using `Ctrl-V` (not `Cmd-V`) inside of some application (ie: source control popup in *IntelliJ IDEA*), lately, it started popping up an OS dialog asking me if I want to `Restart`, `Sleep`, `Cancel` of `Shut Down` (the computer). This is a global / system shortcut that works from applications.

[image]

I have checked in the System Preferences, but I cannot find `Ctrl-V` anywhere.

The questions this situation brings are:

- How to de-assign a global shortcut in the OS?
- What application could I have updated or install lately that would have assign that shortcut?
- Is there a tool to manage global shortcuts or a section in the System Preferences for that?

This is an annoyance since *IntelliJ IDEA* uses `Ctrl-V` as a shortcut and I was using it quite often until this week, when this situation appeared.